# SQL Anywhere 12 Log Searching

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

We have an ERP Program used to create and manage stock / orders. Somehow an order has vanished - this should not be possible. It should be possible to cancel an unwanted order, but never delete it completely.

The order in question was created, printed and sent to a customer - and then disappeared. I know the Primary key and Table info, and want to search the log to see if this was somehow deleted, or perhaps there was a rollback.

How can I translate/search the log in this way?

Please note: I did not write this program, and its not my job to fix it.
I just need to diagnose the issue and contact the SW Vendor, if required, and have them fix it. As such I cannot post any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!!!!

The Sybase Central tool has an option (which I couldn't find in the manual and missed the first time I looked), which can translate a log file into a series of statements and create a *.SQL file.

Tools -> SQL Anywhere -> Translate Log File -> Follow wizard (which hopefully for you is in a language that you speak, for me it was not).

Answer (score 0):

With so little information it is hard to give a definitive answer.

I'd start by searching the regular logs. If you have some kind of audit trail mechanism that would be a great help!

If a search through the regular logs doesn't find you the answer then I would:

1. Get a copy of the database
2. Go through the REDO logs using the appropriate DBA tools. Since I'm not an sqlanywhere DBA I would get help from one.
3. When I found the place in time where the order was deleted I would find any other information I could get. The user that did the commit or users that where logged on at the time (I don't know exactly what kind of information you can get here). Also, go back to the other logs you may have and check around that time stamp.

To learn exactly how to go through the redo logs of an SQL Anywhere database you should first try your google luck and then ask in [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've been googling for hours, can't find any help... All I'm looking for is a way to read the *.log file that the db creates. According to what I have managed to find, this log contains every transaction that the DB performs. I'll look into 'REDO' and see if that can help me.

Comment: Make sure you get a copy of the last backup before the incident and any transaction log file created between the backup and up to and including the time of the incident.

Comment: That much is easy, backups are done daily and seperated per day. The row was created two days ago and noticed missing one day ago, so only two days to look at... I figured out how to read the log file! Will post answer below.